# Style of combs in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using `pgfplots` to create comb figures such as the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[ycomb,color=black] plot coordinates
{(0,3) (1,2) (2,4) (3,1) (4,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I want to change the default color from blue to black. However, the above code only changes the outer boundary of the circles on the top of the combs, while the filled color is still blue. Is there anyone know how to change the inner color ?

Answer (score 14):

The comb ends are markers that you can format via `mark options`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[ycomb,mark options={black}] plot coordinates
{(0,3) (1,2) (2,4) (3,1) (4,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]