# Is it possible to change line styles for pgfplots comb plots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

For example, can I adjust the line thickness, color, or transparency, without also changing the markers?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} 

        \begin{axis}
        
        \addplot+[ycomb] coordinates {(0,3) (1,2) (2,4) (3,1) (4,2)};

        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123981

Comment: That changes the mark options; I'd like to change the line options. (I tried `line options=...` but that gives an error.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set the line options and then (re)set the mark options:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} 

        \begin{axis}
        
        \addplot+[ycomb,red,dash dot, line width=1pt,opacity=0.5, mark options={blue, solid, opacity=1}] coordinates {(0,3) (1,2) (2,4) (3,1) (4,2)};

        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```